# Is it possible to use many to many between 3 models? (GORM)

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

### Is it possible to use many to many between 3 models?

I have 3 models I want to join into a bridge table "client_operator_role"

1. Operator

```
type Operator struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title             string            `gorm:"unique;not null" validate:"required,min=1,max=100"`
    Email             string            `gorm:"not null;unique" validate:"required,email"`
    Mobile            string            `gorm:"not null" validate:"required,min=7,max=15,numeric"`
    Last_online       time.Time         `gorm:"default:null" validate:"omitempty"`
    Last_ip           string            `gorm:"default:null" validate:"omitempty,ip"`
    Clients           []*Client         `gorm:"many2many:client_operator_role;"`
    Cli_ids           []string          `gorm:"-:all" validate:"omitempty,dive,numeric"` // placeholder field, wont be part of table
    GoadminCustomUser GoadminCustomUser `validate:"omitempty,dive"`
}
```

2. Client

```
type Client struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name        string      `gorm:"unique;not null" validate:"required,min=1,max=30"`
    Kyc_status  string      `gorm:"not null" validate:"required,min=1,max=30"`
    Kyc_remarks string      `gorm:"default:null" validate:"omitempty,min=0,max=200"`
    Operators   []*Operator `gorm:"many2many:client_operator_role;"`
    Op_ids      []string    `gorm:"-:all" validate:"omitempty,dive,numeric"` // placeholder field, wont be part of table
    Users       []User
}
```

3. Role

```
type GoadminRole struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name      string
    Slug      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    Operators []*Operator `gorm:"many2many:client_operator_role;"`
}
```

#### Gorm docs state many2many is only for 2 models. Is there a workaround to join these three?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom join table for this. https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Customize-JoinTable

Create bridge table

```golang
type Connection struct {
    gorm.Model

    RoleID     int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    ClientID   int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    OperatorID int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}
```

Add tables' references to each model

```golang
type Operator struct {
    // ..
    Clients []*Client `gorm:"many2many:connections;"`
    Roles   []*Role   `gorm:"many2many:connections;"`
}

type Client struct {
    // ..
    Operators []*Operator `gorm:"many2many:connections;"`
    Roles     []*Role     `gorm:"many2many:connections;"`
}

type Role struct {
    // ..
    Clients   []*Client   `gorm:"many2many:connections;"`
    Operators []*Operator `gorm:"many2many:connections;"`
}
```

Than you should use `SetupJoinTable` func.
Something like that works for me:

```golang
// do not forget to check for errors
db.SetupJoinTable(&models.Operator{}, "Roles", &models.Connection{})
db.SetupJoinTable(&models.Operator{}, "Clients", &models.Connection{})

db.SetupJoinTable(&models.Client{}, "Roles", &models.Connection{})
db.SetupJoinTable(&models.Client{}, "Operators", &models.Connection{})

db.SetupJoinTable(&models.Role{}, "Clients", &models.Connection{})
db.SetupJoinTable(&models.Role{}, "Operators", &models.Connection{})
```